# Tikz, tkz-euclide does not work

Tags: tkz-euclide

I made this code, but when I press F5 it keeps running infinitely and doesn't produce any results. It is the first time I use the tikz package in LaTeX and I have no experience.  (I'm using Ubuntu).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{ 0/0/O,
                       8/0/A,
                       12.5/0/C}
        \tkzDefPoints(45:9.6){B}           
        \tkzDefLine[parallel=through C](A,B)
        \tkzDrawPoints(O, A, B, C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working version of the code you shared above. I hope it's helpful

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % tikz is loaded by tkz-euclide

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,
                  8/0/A,
                  12.5/0/C}
    \tkzDefPoint(45:9.6){B}
    \tkzDefLine[parallel=through C](A,B)
    \tkzDrawPoints(O, A, B, C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! The problem was the "s" in the line \tkzDefPoint(45:9.6){B}. Thank you.